# How does the small change in the unit vector $\,=\,$ the small change in the angular displacement?

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

How does the small change in the unit vector $\,=\,$ the small change in the angular displacement?

I saw this on a book:

[image]

How does the small change in the radius equal the small change in angular displacement, and that too in the direction of the angular displacement?

Am I apprehending this wrong? Since I learnt length $= \theta*r.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to see why if you wrote these unit vectors in component form:
$$\underline{\hat{r}}=\left(\begin{matrix}\cos\theta\\\sin\theta\end{matrix}\right)$$ and
$$\underline{\hat{\theta}}=\left(\begin{matrix}-\sin\theta\\\cos\theta\end{matrix}\right)$$

Now differentiate with respect to $t$:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\underline{\hat{r}}=\left(\begin{matrix}-\sin\theta\\\cos\theta\end{matrix}\right)\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\underline{\hat{\theta}}\dot{\theta}$$

and $$\frac{d}{dt}\underline{\hat{\theta}}=\left(\begin{matrix}-\cos\theta\\-\sin\theta\end{matrix}\right)\frac{d\theta}{dt}=-\underline{\hat{r}}\dot{\theta}$$